# How to handle SIGABRT signal in unix

Tags: unix, coredump, abort, sigabrt

I am getting core dump while running below program:

```
$ cat test2.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main()
{

abort();

}

$

$ cc -o test2 test2.c
"test2.c", line 5: warning #2951-D: return type of function "main" must be
          "int"
  void main()
       ^

$ ./test2
Abort(coredump)
$
```

I have received a SIGABRT signal. Kindly suggest me the ways to handle this SIGABRT signal.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGABRT

Answer (score 3):

remove `abort()` from your main...
if you want to leave main: `return;`
if you want to leave the program in any place: `exit()`

if you really want to handle the signal, install a signal handler
see: http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/sigaction/

hth

Mario

Answer (score 3):

You normally should not handle it, the purpose of calling abort() is to produce a core dump and terminate your program, just as your program does.

Answer (score 2):

```
// here's same code w/signal handler
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void abort_handler(int);

void main()
{
    if (signal(SIGABRT, abort_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't set signal handler\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    abort();
    exit(0);
}

void abort_handler(int i)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Caught SIGABRT, exiting application\n");
    exit(1);
}
$ cc -o test test.c
$ ./test
Caught SIGABRT, exiting application
$
```

Comment: be aware that you can handle SIGABRT but not you can not stop the process from terminating (and dumping)

Comment: I don't know to what degree that statement is system dependent, on the system I compiled and ran the above code, no core was dumped.
</br>

$ uname -a 


Linux nas 2.6.32-30-generic #59-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 1 21:30:46 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux


See man signal, as well as man 7 signal